NSIS nsExec returns command it self
Function .onInstSuccess

ExpandEnvStrings $R0 %COMSPEC%
ExecWait '"$R0" /c reg save "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\${RegUninstall}" "${SettingPath}registry.dat" /y'
nsExec::Exec '"$INSTDIR\Service\${ServiceExeName}" install'
nsExec::Exec '"$INSTDIR\Service\${ServiceExeName}" start'
nsExec::Exec 'rundll32.exe syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultInstall 128 $INSTDIR\usbflt.inf'
nsExec::Exec 'sc.exe start usbflt'

nsExec::Exec 'sc.exe create sample binpath= "$INSTDIR\x64\sample.exe"'
nsExec::Exec 'sc.exe config sample start= auto'
nsExec::Exec 'sc.exe start sample'
nsExec::Exec '"$INSTDIR\ServiceMonitor\Sample.Monitor.exe" /i'

FunctionEnd

I'm making an installer with nsis and using it, but there's no problem with other pcs, but I'm only getting a problem with the above code in a specific pc.
I tried to output a return value every middle to find where the problem occurred, and the other part returned 0, but only
nsExec::Exec 'sc.exe create sample binpath= "$INSTDIR\x64\sample.exe"'
nsExec::Exec '"$INSTDIR\ServiceMonitor\Sample.Monitor.exe" /i'
these 2 returned the same string as the command and not executed.
And what's more confusing is when I use
nsExec::Exec 'cmd /c sc.exe create sample binpath= "$INSTDIR\x64\sample.exe"'
nsExec::Exec 'cmd /c "$"$INSTDIR\ServiceMonitor\sample.Monitor.exe$" /i'
cmd /c solve the problem
I want to know what caused the problem and why it was solved by using cmd/c, can anybody tell me about it?
